# for loop associated query in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is it giving 1th instead of 1st?

```
a=1
i=None
for i in "abcdef":
    print("{}{} character is: {}".format(a,x,i))
    if a==1:
        x="st"
    elif a==2:
        x="nd"
    elif a==3:
        x="rd"
    elif a>=4:
        x="th"
    a+=1
```

Result:

```
'1th character is: a'
'2st character is: b'
'3nd character is: c'
'4rd character is: d'
'5th character is: e'
'6th character is: f'
```

Comment: First, you need to calculate `x` before you try to use it in `print`.

Comment: As far as how to get `a`: the `ord` function gives you the Unicode number for a character, like 97 for `a` and 100 for `d`, so you can easily get the number it sounds like you want from that

Comment: Or if you just want the position within the string: `for a, i in enumerate(“abcdef”, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, much appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your print statement comes before the correct value of x is initiated.

```
a=1
i=None
for i in "abcdef":
     if a==1:
        x="st"
     elif a==2:
        x="nd"
     elif a==3:
        x="rd"
     elif a>=4:
        x="th"
     print("{}{} character is: {}".format(a,x,i))
     a+=1
```